# How to select the latest record of each hour in a day?

Tags: mysql, mysql-5

I want to select the latest record of each hour in a given date, based on the datetime column 'reading_on' in my table. What is the best way to do it? I already tried group by HOUR(reading_on) with HAVING("max(HOUR(reading_on))"), but I didn't get the proper result.

Below is my table structure

[image]

Answer (score 2):

That's a [groupwise maximum](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/755918/simple-query-to-grab-max-value-for-each-id).
You may plump for a null-self-join:

```
SELECT  ir1.*
FROM inverter_readings IR1
LEFT JOIN inverter_readings IR2 ON
DATE(IR1.READING_ON) = DATE(IR2.READING_ON) AND
HOUR(IR1.READING_ON) = HOUR(IR2.READING_ON) AND
IR1.READING_ON  < IR2.READING_ON
WHERE IR2.id IS NULL
```

***[sqlfiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f471c3/1)***.

Answer (score 0):

To lookup the maximum id value for each hour on May 10, 2014

```
SET @GivenDate = '2014-05-10';
SET @dt1 = @GivenDate + INTERVAL 0 SECOND;
SET @dt2 = @GivenDate + INTERVAL 1 DAY - INTERVAL 1 SECOND;
SELECT A.HourRange,B.* FROM
(
    SELECT MAX(id) id,HourRange
    (
        SELECT id,(DATE(@reading_on) + INTERVAL HOUR(@reading_on) HOUR HourRange
        FROM inverter_readings WHERE reading_on >= @dt1 AND reading_on <= @dt2
    ) AA
    GROUP BY HourRange
) A LEFT JOIN inverter_readings B USING (id);
```

Give it a Try !!!